# Using d3.js v4 - using parentId to resolve ambiguity

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to understand the right usage to achieve my collapsible tree d3 but unable to establish the proper parent/child references since I cannot use "parent". Attempting to use parentID.

This is my dataset I am testing with:

```
    var result = [
      { "id": 1, "name": "Top Level", "parent": null, "parentId": "" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "PROD", "parent": "Top Level", "parentId": 1 },
      { "id": 3, "name": "QAT", "parent": "Top Level", "parentId": 1 },
      { "id": 4, "name": "App1", "parent": "PROD", "parentId": 2 },
      { "id": 5, "name": "App1", "parent": "QAT", "parentId": 3 },
      { "id": 6, "name": "ServerPROD001", "parent": "App1", "parentId": 4 },
      { "id": 7, "name": "ServerQAT001", "parent": "App1", "parentId": 5 }
    ];
```

and based on the collapsible tree:

```
        // convert the flat data into a hierarchy 
        var treeData = d3.stratify()
          .id(function (d) { return d.name; })
          .parentId(function (d) { return d.parent })
          (result);
```

This works fine if I do not include items 6 and 7. If I do include these I get an ambiguity error which makes sense because it cannot determine which "App1" to associate to.

I tried changing the code to use the parentId but just get an error of "missing:1" now.

```
        // convert the flat data into a hierarchy 
        var treeData = d3.stratify()
          .id(function (d) { return d.name; })
          .parentId(function (d) { return d.parentId })
          (result);
```

Note - I cannot change the "App1" name values to something unique as they will exist in multiple areas with that given name.

Comment: `.id(function (d) { return d.id; }).parentId(function (d) { return d.parentId })` ?

Comment: mkaran - let me try that, I see that I may not be returning d.id

Comment: That does run without error but it displays the d.id in the tree, so I see "1", "2", etc... I need the "name" to appear.

Comment: Manually assign the name `treeData.each(function(d) {
    d.name = d.data.name;
  });` Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/am87msdz/  (basically taken from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/e7e37cfe0e8763cb0915dee33cc2a24b) )

Comment: I see what I missed there. Thank you very much mkaran! Made my day!

Comment: I m glad I helped :)

Comment: Please post as an answer so I can mark it up for you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the id that is unique and not the name:

```
// convert the flat data into a hierarchy 
var treeData = d3.stratify()
          .id(function (d) { return d.id; }) // return the id instead of the name
          .parentId(function (d) { return d.parentId })
          (result);
```

and then set the name you need to be displayed like this:

```
// assign the name to each node as the initial name
treeData.each(function(d) {
    d.name = d.data.name;
  });
```

A working example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/am87msdz/), based on [this](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/e7e37cfe0e8763cb0915dee33cc2a24b)
:)

Good luck!